# CSS: place text left and right around a centered image

Tags: html, css

I want to place text to the left and to the right around a centered image.
See:

```
<div style="position:relative; display: table; margin: 2em auto;">
    <span>TEXTSAMPLE 12345</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="height: 4em;">
    <span>12345</span>
 </div>
```

I figured out how to center the whole thing but I want the image to be dead centered and adjust the text accordingly.

Tried with float but I'm not getting a proper result. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the parent, then `flex-grow` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short) on the text divs so they will fill all of the available space left over by the image (putting the image in the center), then use `text-align` in the first span to put the text by the image. I also wrapped your `img` in an element since `img`'s as flex children usually end up stretching.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

span:not(.img) {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>TEXTSAMPLE 12345</span>
  <span class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="height: 4em;"></span>
  <span>12345</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option - display:flex for centering content both horizontally and vertically

CSS:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;

}
body, div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <span>TEXTSAMPLE 12345</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="height: 4em;">
    <span>12345</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vmeYzb

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table without borders with 3 columns and 1 line. In the first and in the last cell you put your text how you want; in the central you put the image:

```
<table>
<tr>text 1</tr>
<tr><img...></tr>
<tr>text 2</tr>
</table>
```